# XPath expression -hierarchy

Tags: xpath, axes

```
    <div class="summary-item">
       <label  >Price</label>
        <div class="value">
            0.99 GBP
         </div>
   </div>


    <div class="summary-item">
       <label  >Other info</label>
       <div class="value">
           All languages
       </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get the **"0.99 GBP"** using an XPath expression, so far I have reached the label  using this (note there is another class by the name summary-item, therefore I need to uniquely identify with the label name Price)

```
sel.xpath('//*/div[@class="summary-item"]/label[text()="Price"]').extract()
```

However, I am unable to get to the class, I tried using following-sibling, but I did not succeed, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of child nodes can be part of the predicate. Put the test for `label` into a predicate for the parent, either as a separate predicate (adding the target node as well):

```
//div[@class="summary-item"][label[text()="Price"]]/div[@class="value"]
```

or joined with `and`:

```
//div[@class="summary-item" and label[text()="Price"]]/div[@class="value"]
```

(Note you don’t need `//*/div` at the start.)

You could use `following-sibling` if you wanted, it would look like this:

```
//div[@class="summary-item"]/label[text()="Price"]/following-sibling::div[@class="value"]
```

(here the `label` div *isn’t* part of the predicate).

One more thing to be aware of, using XPath to select HTML classes doesn’t work the same as using CSS – XPath will only match the exact string whereas CSS matches even if the element is in more than one class. In this case it works out okay but you should watch out for it. Search StackOverflow if it will be an issue, there are a few answers descibing it.